# Rationale behind C library functions never setting errno to zero

Tags: c, standards

The C standard mandates that no C standard library functions shall set `errno` to zero. Why exactly is this?

I could understand it being useful for calling several functions, and only checking `errno` after the last one - for example:

```
errno = 0;
double x = strtod(str1, NULL);
long y = strtol(str2, NULL);
if (errno)
    // either "strtod" or "strtol" failed
else
    // both succeeded
```

However, is this not considered "bad practice"? Since you're only checking `errno` at the very end, you only know that one of the functions *did* fail, but not *which* function failed. Is simply knowing that *something* failed good enough for most practical programs?

I tried looking for various C Rationale documents, but many of them don't have much detail for `<errno.h>`.

Comment: I guess it's "don't pay for what you don't want". If you care about `errno`, you can always set it to zero yourself.

Comment: Something else to be aware of is that a function can set `errno` to a non-zero value even if it succeeds. (It might call some other function that fails, but that doesn't constitute a failure in the outer function.)

Answer (score 12):

The C library does not set `errno` to 0 for historical reasons<sup>1</sup>. POSIX no longer claims its libraries will not alter the value in case of success, and [the new Linux man page for `errno.h`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) reflects this:

> The `<errno.h>` header file defines the integer variable `errno`, which is set by system calls and some library functions in the event of an error to indicate what went wrong. Its value is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., `-1` from most system calls; `-1` or `NULL` from most library functions); **a function that succeeds *is* allowed to change `errno`.**

The [ANSI C Rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d1.html#errno-4-1-3) states that the committee felt it was more practical to adopt and standardize the existing practice of using `errno`.

> The error reporting machinery centered about the setting of `errno` is generally regarded with tolerance at best.  It requires a ``pathological coupling'' between library functions and makes use of a static writable memory cell, which interferes with the construction of shareable libraries.  Nevertheless, the Committee preferred to standardize this existing, however deficient, machinery rather than invent something more ambitious.

There is almost always a way to check for error outside of checking if `errno` got set. Checking if `errno` got set is not always reliable, since some calls require calling a separate API to get the error reason. For instance, `ferror()` is used to check for an error if you get a short result from `fread()` or `fwrite()`.

Interestingly enough, your example of using `strtod()` is one of the cases where setting `errno` to 0 before the call is **required** to correctly detect if an error has occurred. All the `strto*()` string to number functions have this requirement, because a valid return value is returned even in the face of an error.

```
errno = 0;
char *endptr;
double x = strtod(str1, &endptr);
if (endptr == str1) {
    /*...parse error */
} else if (errno == ERANGE) {
    if (x == 0) {
        /*...underflow */
    } else if (x == HUGE_VAL) {
        /*...positive overflow */
    } else if (x == -HUGE_VAL) {
        /*...negative overflow */
    } else {
        /*...unknown range error? */
    }
}
```

The above code is based on the behavior of [`strtod()` as documented on Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod). The C standard only stipulates that underflow cannot return a value greater than the smallest positive `double`, and whether or not `errno` is set to `ERANGE` is implementation defined<sup>2</sup>.

There is actually an extensive [cert advisory write-up](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6619179) that recommends always setting `errno` to 0 before a library call and checking its value *after the call indicates a failure has occurred*. This is because some library calls will set `errno` even if the call itself was successful<sup>3</sup>.

> The value of `errno` is 0 at program startup, but it is never set to 0 by any library function. The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in the C Standard. It is meaningful for a program to inspect the contents of `errno` only after an error has been reported. More precisely, **`errno` is meaningful only after a library function that sets `errno` on error has returned an error code.**

---

<sub>1. Previously I claimed it was to avoid masking an error from an earlier call. I can't find any evidence to support this claim. I also had a bogus `printf()` example.</sub>
<sub>2. Thanks to @chux for pointing this out. Reference is C.11 §7.22.1.3 ¶10.</sub>
<sub>3. Pointed out by @KeithThompson in a comment.</sub>

Comment: Minor issue: it appears underflow could result in a non-0 result: "the functions return a value whose magnitude is no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type" C11 7.22.1.3.10.

Comment: @chux: Thanks. I'll make an edit. Since setting `errno` to `ERANGE` is implementation defined in the case of underflow, there is actually no portable way to detect underflow. My code followed what I found in the Linux man page on my system.

Comment: Your comments about the `strto*` functions is exactly why I asked if my example would be considered bad practice, but it's the only way in which `errno` not being set to zero would be useful, or even apply.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I guess the only point you can take is that `errno` may get set even in the case of success, so just using the fact it got set is not really a good enough indicator that an error occurred. You have to check the results of the individual calls themselves to know if an error happened at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do error check for both of the function call, if you really care about.

```
errno = 0;
double x = strtod(str1, NULL);
if (errno)
    // strtod"  failed
else
    // "strtod" succeeded

long y = strtol(str2, NULL);
if (errno)
    // "strtol" failed
else
    // "strtol" succeeded
```

Since we never know how mach function called in a process , how can the lib set errnos for each function call, Right?

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrarily changing the errorno is analogous to 'catching and swallowing' an exception.  Before there were exceptions that would propagate through different layers of a program and finally reach a point where the caller will either catch and respond to the exception in some way or simple pass the buck, there were errnos.  Not altering the errno, unless you are somehow handling, overriding, treating as irrelevant, the error, is essential to this first generation error handling propagation paradigm.